# Wordpress get the category name on each category

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to make the code to display 'MORE STORIES FROM #CATEGORYNAME' as a title of the box that appears. As the user is viewing different category the name to change.

Ex. User is viewing a post in category 'cars' when the box appears the title would be MORE STORIES FROM 'cars'.

When he switch to category 'IT', the name to be 'MORE STORIES FROM IT'

```
if(!emptry($td_query_more_article->posts)) {?>
    <div class="td-more-articles-box">
     <i class=td-icon-close td-close-more-articles-box"></i>
     <span class="td-more-articles-box-title"><?php echo __td('MORE STORIES', TD_THEME_NAME) ?></span>
    <div class="td-content-more-articles-box">
```

I hope I was specific enough. Corrent me if I am wrong

Comment: The WordPress Codex has plenty of info - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/

Comment: Hi, I saw them, but I am not really sure how to properly use them

Comment: OK, are you in the 'loop' here? Also, do posts have more than one category?

Comment: Not usually, but they might have more than one category. When this happens I guess it would get the primary category setting.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this needs bit more clarification how you want to achieve this; do you want this on widget or add it statically on the theme? Is there a reason why excisting plugins don't work for you?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the respond ! There are plugins, yes, but i'd like to learn coding.  And yes it is for a widget.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the WordPress loop, you can simply using the following:

```
$categories = get_the_category();

if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
    echo esc_html( $categories[0]->name );   
}
```

This will give you the first category if there are more than one.

If you are not in the loop, you will need to pass the post id as a parameter, like this;

```
// get the post object
global $post; 

// pass post id
$categories = get_the_category($post->ID); 

if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
    echo esc_html( $categories[0]->name );   
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but what does "you are in the loop means"?

Comment: I think you should do some reading to ensure you understand the basics of how WordPress works. Here's a link to the loop page, but I'd start with some basic lessons from the codex https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop . Understanding the basics will make things a lot easier.

Comment: I already found it and read it. But i can't make it work. Any additional help?

Comment: What happens when you use one of the code options above?

Comment: The box stopped to appear.

Comment: Put this before your php code (still within the PHP tags), ensuring you have error reporting switched on and that errors are set to be displayed: error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1); I can see you have spelt empty wrong in the code snippet you posted for starters

Comment: Managed to do it, but it doesn't get the primary category. It just get the Featured now. And how can I make the categoryname to be hyperlink to that category?

Comment: To be more specific it now gets the category that is marked and is at the top in the panel.

Answer (score 0):

You can get category name using this function.

$cat_name = get_category(get_query_var('cat'))->name;